# Strange CSS gap difference between Firefox vs Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I have an issue which I've been completely baffled by.

I am currently working on a client's site and on Chrome, the navigation bar has a 1px gap on the very right (more noticeable when you hover "contact") however firefox is fine. BUT on Firefox if you go onto (http://meskholdings.com/about) there is a massive gap, yet on Chrome its not there.

Been trying to deal with this all day and I cant figure out whats going on!

Comment: You are aware that you have a div inside of the head-element? I don't know how fb stuff is supposed to work but that just seems wrong.

Comment: you could try to float the last nav item right, this does cause some other issues however.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to get inconsistent results when it comes to dealing with pixel fractions.  I suggest replacing the padding on your anchor elements (0 left and right padding), give the anchor element text-align center and a width of 20%.

```
nav li a {
  width:20%;
  padding:10px 0;
  text-align:center;
}
```